# Complicated model causes slowness/poor performance

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Below you will find a CodeIgniter model called `getCalls` to which I am passing the following values from the controller `$manager, $level, $department, $id`

**Inside I do the following actions:**

1. I check the level of the logged-in user and point him/her to the proper code
2. I collect all the data that needs to be in the view in an array called `$callInfo`

*I create an index in the database over all joined columns.*

I am facing a speed issue when calling the controller that handles this model. Firebug tells me that it takes about 30 seconds to load the page.

Please note that the server performance and specs are not as good as you would expect. Also this is the only "complicated screen" that runs slowly and I don't have any problems with the code below, just a speed issue.

Please note that I am calling the page via $.ajax and you can find the function below...

**PLEASE ADVISE**

```
function getCalls($manager, $level, $department, $id){
        $callInfo = array();
        $empMeta = array();
        $MetaEmp = array();     
        $callMeta = array();
        $MetaCall = array();
        $TheCall = array();

        if($manager == true && $level == '3'){
            $query = $this->db->query("SELECT id_call, name_co, callStatus_call, dueDate_call, idemp_call FROM ecc_calls_call JOIN ecc_employees_emp ON idemp_call = id_emp JOIN ecc_company_co ON idco_call = id_co JOIN ecc_mempership_memper ON idemp_memper = idemp_call JOIN ecc_department_dep ON id_dep = iddep_memper WHERE status_call = 'active' && name_dep = {$department} ORDER BY id_call DESC");             
            if($query->num_rows() >= 1){
                foreach($query->result() as $row){
                    //employee meta
                    $employee = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM ecc_employee_empmeta WHERE idemp_empmeta = {$row->idemp_call}");
                    if($employee->num_rows() >= 1){
                        foreach($employee->result() as $rowEmp){
                            $empMeta[$rowEmp->metaKey_empmeta] = $rowEmp->metaValue_empmeta;
                        };
                        $MetaEmp = array(
                            'first_name' => $empMeta['first_name'],
                            'last_name' => $empMeta['last_name'],
                            'position' => $empMeta['position'],
                            'avatar' => $empMeta['avatar'],
                            'mobile' => $empMeta['mobile']        
                        );
                        //return $MetaEmp;
                    }                   
                    //call meta
                    $call = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM ecc_call_cmeta WHERE idcall_cmeta = {$row->id_call}");
                    if($call->num_rows() >= 1){
                        foreach($call->result() as $rowCall){
                           $callMeta[$rowCall->metaKey_cmeta] = $rowCall->metaValue_cmeta;
                        };
                        $MetaCall = array(
                            'inDate' => $callMeta['inDate'],
                            'feedback' => $callMeta['feedback'],
                            'reason' => $callMeta['reason']        
                        );
                    }       
                    $callInfo['id'] = $row->id_call;
                    $callInfo['name'] = $MetaEmp['first_name'] . " " . $MetaEmp['last_name'];
                    $callInfo['inDate'] = $MetaCall['inDate'];
                    $callInfo['feedback'] = $MetaCall['feedback'];
                    $callInfo['reason'] = $MetaCall['reason'];
                    $callInfo['company'] = $row->name_co;
                    $callInfo['dueDate_call'] = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($row->dueDate_call));
                    $callInfo['callStatus_call'] = $row->callStatus_call;   
                    $TheCall[] = $callInfo;         
                }//foreach call
            }//if
            return $TheCall;                

        }elseif($level == 1){
            $query = $this->db->query("SELECT id_call, name_co, callStatus_call, dueDate_call, idemp_call  FROM ecc_calls_call JOIN ecc_employees_emp ON idemp_call = id_emp JOIN ecc_company_co ON idco_call = id_co WHERE status_call = 'active' ORDER BY id_call DESC");             
            if($query->num_rows() >= 1){
                foreach($query->result() as $row){
                    //employee meta
                    $employee = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM ecc_employee_empmeta WHERE idemp_empmeta = {$row->idemp_call}");
                    if($employee->num_rows() >= 1){
                        foreach($employee->result() as $rowEmp){
                            $empMeta[$rowEmp->metaKey_empmeta] = $rowEmp->metaValue_empmeta;
                        }
                        $MetaEmp = array(
                            'first_name' => $empMeta['first_name'],
                            'last_name' => $empMeta['last_name'],
                            'position' => $empMeta['position'],
                            'avatar' => $empMeta['avatar'],
                            'mobile' => $empMeta['mobile']        
                        );
                        //return $MetaEmp;
                    }                   
                    //call meta
                    $call = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM ecc_call_cmeta WHERE idcall_cmeta = {$row->id_call}");
                    if($call->num_rows() >= 1){
                        foreach($call->result() as $rowCall){
                            $callMeta[$rowCall->metaKey_cmeta] = $rowCall->metaValue_cmeta;
                        }
                        $MetaCall = array(
                            'inDate' => $callMeta['inDate'],
                            'feedback' => $callMeta['feedback'],
                            'reason' => $callMeta['reason']        
                        );
                    }       
                    $callInfo['id'] = $row->id_call;
                    $callInfo['name'] = $MetaEmp['first_name'] . " " . $MetaEmp['last_name'];
                    $callInfo['inDate'] = $MetaCall['inDate'];
                    $callInfo['feedback'] = $MetaCall['feedback'];
                    $callInfo['reason'] = $MetaCall['reason'];
                    $callInfo['company'] = $row->name_co;
                    $callInfo['dueDate_call'] = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($row->dueDate_call));
                    $callInfo['callStatus_call'] = $row->callStatus_call;   
                    $TheCall[] = $callInfo;         
                }//foreach call
            }//if
            return $TheCall;                
        }elseif($level == 3){
            $query = $this->db->query("SELECT id_call, name_co, callStatus_call, dueDate_call, idemp_call FROM ecc_calls_call JOIN ecc_employees_emp ON idemp_call = id_emp JOIN ecc_company_co ON idco_call = id_co WHERE status_call = 'active' && idemp_call = {$id} ORDER BY id_call DESC");                
            if($query->num_rows() >= 1){
                foreach($query->result() as $row){
                    //employee meta
                    $employee = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM ecc_employee_empmeta WHERE idemp_empmeta = {$row->idemp_call}");
                    if($employee->num_rows() >= 1){
                        foreach($employee->result() as $rowEmp){
                            $empMeta[$rowEmp->metaKey_empmeta] = $rowEmp->metaValue_empmeta;
                        }
                        $MetaEmp = array(
                            'first_name' => $empMeta['first_name'],
                            'last_name' => $empMeta['last_name'],
                            'position' => $empMeta['position'],
                            'avatar' => $empMeta['avatar'],
                            'mobile' => $empMeta['mobile']        
                        );
                        //return $MetaEmp;
                    }                   
                    //call meta
                    $call = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM ecc_call_cmeta WHERE idcall_cmeta = {$row->id_call}");
                    if($call->num_rows() >= 1){
                        foreach($call->result() as $rowCall){
                            $callMeta[$rowCall->metaKey_cmeta] = $rowCall->metaValue_cmeta;
                        }
                        $MetaCall = array(
                            'inDate' => $callMeta['inDate'],
                            'feedback' => $callMeta['feedback'],
                            'reason' => $callMeta['reason']        
                        );
                    }       
                    $callInfo['id'] = $row->id_call;
                    $callInfo['name'] = $MetaEmp['first_name'] . " " . $MetaEmp['last_name'];
                    $callInfo['inDate'] = $MetaCall['inDate'];
                    $callInfo['feedback'] = $MetaCall['feedback'];
                    $callInfo['reason'] = $MetaCall['reason'];
                    $callInfo['company'] = $row->name_co;
                    $callInfo['dueDate_call'] = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($row->dueDate_call));
                    $callInfo['callStatus_call'] = $row->callStatus_call;   
                    $TheCall[] = $callInfo;         
                }//foreach call
            }//if
            return $TheCall;                                
        }
}
```

**Here is the ajax function...**

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: "<?php echo base_url() . 'boffice/dataTable/'; ?>" + type + "/" + arg,
    //data: {},//add variables
    beforeSend:function(){
        //this is were the loading image load
        $('.PreviewHere').append('<div class="preloading"><img src="<?php echo base_url() . "assets/images/loading.gif"; ?>" alt="تحميل" /></div>').show();
    },
    success: function(data){
        //successful request, do somthing with the data
        $('.PreviewHere').html(data).show();
        $(".preloading").remove();
    },
    error: function(){
        //failed request
    },
    datatype: 'html'
})//ajax
```

Comment: 1) Way too much logic in a single function. Break that apart, please. 2) You are executing multiple SQL statements inside of a `foreach` loop. Unless you _really_ know that you **need** to do it this way, there's almost always a better option. In this particular case, you can join or get all of the IDs and execute one `SELECT ... WHERE id IN (...)` afterwards. Remember, in a production environment even a 2ms database query really has at least a 10ms overhead (when you factor in latency, connection times, etc).

Comment: @ColinMorelli how do you advice to breaking the logic of checking the level, your effort is very appreciated, also how could i write all the statement in one query.

Comment: @ColinMorelli do you advice to break the code inside the model to three other classes and call every class in the proper place